# Get null when running JWTAuth::user() in Laravel

Tags: laravel, jwt

I've been using JWT for authentication in Laravel. I have a JWTMiddleware to check authorization, which works fine, like the following.

```
try {
    JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    return response()->json(['error' => 'Token is Invalid']);
}
```

**User model**

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements JWTSubject
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function ($model) {
            $model->uuid = Str::uuid()->toString();
        });

        static::saving(function ($model) {
            $original_uuid = $model->getOriginal('uuid');
            if ($original_uuid !== $model->uuid) {
                $model->uuid = $original_uuid;
            }
        });
    }

    public function getJWTIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    public function getJWTCustomClaims()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Now I have a route that uses this middleware and returns an authenticated user.

```
Route::middleware(['jwt.verify'])->group(function () {
   Route::post('/user', function () {
       $user = JWTAuth::user();
       return response()->json($user);
   });
});
```

After entering this route, I get null. Why does the middleware work fine, yet I can not retrieve the user?